# Reachability App 2.2 - Local Wifi does not restore

Tags: iphone, ios4, reachability

Can somebody explain why the reachability app behaves strangely?
I built it under IOS 4.2

When I start it, all three text boxes show an available network.

If I turn the airport off, they all show no connection.

Turning the Airport back on again only Remote Host and TCP/IP routing are shown as availabl. Local Wifi remains 'Access not available'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may seem like a dumb question, but did you build it in the simulator? Results on the simulator won't mirror those on the device, as the 3G in the simulator is simply an abstraction of the wifi radio in your Mac. You'll need to use a device in order to see it work.

Comment: Thank you for your "not dumb" question. Of course I was testing on the Mac. I will try it on the phone and get back with the results.